# Determining the favicon file (.ico extension) on the client side?

Tags: javascript

I know this is possible because this is how bookmarklets work for social bookmarking sites like delicious.

1. Google has an API that will pull it for you but it only works about 80% of the time.
2. Checking the default location host.com/favicon.ico does not work very often, maybe 50%.

The links I'm looking for look like this:

```
<link href="/static/27009/images/favicon.ico>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" />
```

One idea was to load the site into a `visibility:none` iframe and pull the information out, by searching the text for `xxxx.ico`.

Or if it is possible to access the iframe dom and just grab it that way.

How do I pull the favicon location client side?

Comment: Welcome to [SO] please take some time to review the [faq]. It would be helpful if you posted the code were trying to use.

Comment: I don't have any code to post, I'm trying to come up with a strategy and then write the code.

Comment: search the dom for `<link rel="shortcut icon">` elements, grab the `[href]` of the first, if none exist, use `/favicon.ico`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about older browsers, you can use `document.querySelector` to get the favicon `<link>` element:

```
var link,
    favicon;
link = document.querySelector('link[rel="shortcut icon"]');
favicon = link ? link.href : '/favicon.ico';
```

Comment: I saw code similar to this on the delicious bookmarklet....how do i select the document...this is client side on someone else's web site..given a url...for example..i'm at www.delicous.com and i want the favicon at www.google.com.

Comment: I've been told this is impossible currently...is your method for same host clients...I'm on www.delicous.com and I want the title of www.delicious.com ?

Comment: You can't access another page except where allowed by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If you're on `http://example.com/foo` you could get the favicon for `http://example.com/bar` (assuming they were different), but you'd never have access to `http://sample.com/`.